# Как настроить RSA ключи для убунты?

Tags: rsa, ubuntu

Как настроить RSA ключи для убунты? Хочу сделать авторизацию пользователей через ssh  по ключам.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна команда `ssh-keygen`